# How to use Texture Influence with Particle System size

Tags: particles

https://i.imgur.com/XrfZgeZ.mp4

I’m trying to use a blend texture with size influence on my particle system. I want my particles to start small and then big over their lifetime.

As you can see, the cutoff moves as the animation goes. I don’t have any keyframed values.

I’d like the cutoff to be fixed relative to the emitter. How can I achieve that? What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Maybe instanced object itself have some animated scaling...

Comment: No, they have no scaling. I have no keyframed values

Comment: Could you send a file?

Comment: What happens if you delete the bake and turn off the effectors?

Comment: Uploaded a blend file.

When I turn of my effector and rebake my simulation, the texture works properly. However I need that effector...